# Conditional jsx elements React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, jsx

I try to display a text when webview is loaded but ActivityIndicator doesn't dissapear.

I've tried to create a hook with a boolean variable which changes when webview is loaded, then it would should show the text "Hello, I am your cat!" in the first condition.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';


const Cat = () => {
  return (
    <Cat />
  );
}
const Cafe = () => {
  const [ok, setOk] = useState(false);
  return (
      ok ?
      
    <Text>Hello, I am your cat!</Text>
      :
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{height: 0, width: 0}}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: "https://www.google.com/"}}
          onLoad={() => {
            setOk(true)
            console.log(ok);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#E60081"/>
    </View>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Cafe;
```

Comment: For me it shows `Hello, I am your cat!` at first.

Comment: I think that happens because I'm using a online editor. But can you see activity indicator before text?

Comment: Even i was using Online Editor. No i did not see any Spinner. Can you share your snack link?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@zentyx/your-cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were passing a reference to your `onLoad` function. Try below code.

```
<WebView
  source={{uri: "https://www.google.com/"}}
  onLoad={setOk(true)}
/>
```